# Add a custom image or custom background color as chat background

Tags: react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

I am using `react-native-gifted-chat`, I want to add a background image (or at least a background color) for the chat but I cannot seem to find the prop. Can someone help?

My current implementation is

```
    <GiftedChat
      messages={messagesState}
      onSend={(message: IMessage[]) => onSend(message)}
      user={{
        _id: 1,
      }}
      renderAvatarOnTop
      isTyping={mutationLoading}
      onInputTextChanged={debouncedOnInputTextChanged}
      listViewProps={{
        onEndReached: onFetchMore,
      }}
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

messageContainerStyle={{backgroundColor: 'red'}} // add this prop in gifted Chat

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<ImageBackground>` component from `react-native`.

Example Usage:

```
<ImageBackground resizeMode='cover' imageStyle={{ opacity: 0.07 }} source={require('../../../assets/chatBackground.png')} style={{ flex: 1 }}>    
    <GiftedChat ...props/>
</ImageBackground >
```